# C++ VS2013 Debugger Breakpoint: Not Hit

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I have a relatively simple C++ console project that does some calculations and writes an output file. I am trying to determine why the output file does not have the correct output. Instead, I have been struggling with the debugger.

For some reason I cannot add a break point *after a certain line in a certain function*.

[image]

All breakpoints placed after line 1106 up to line 1214 (the end of the function) are not reachable.

[image]

**EDIT:** I have moved the specific code shown in the first image up in the function and it breaks no problem but now I cannot break between line 1079 and the function end. I renamed the function but that made no difference.

When I look at the disassembly, I notice a strange thing at line 1078:

[image]

I'm not sure that this makes a difference but the statement after 1078 (line 962) refers to an object named CSVData of type string. The string is created blank but filled at run-time with a large number of characters. I was originally thinking stack overflow (no pun) but the breakpoint is disabled at application start which is long before (10-15 mins) before the CSVData object is populated.

The first thought would be: Use the previous breakpoint instead. However, when I step to the next line, it takes me to a section of code that I know for sure is not executing (It's in another function entirely). It continues jumping around in a predetermined but not source-relevant pattern. Please help me. I'm losing my mind on this one!

I have Google'd this extensively before asking here. I have tried the following things:

- Deleting all files
- Creating new Win32 console project and adding only
  the 5 headers and 5 source files.
- Resetting Visual Studio settings
- Disable Optimization
- Un-check "Require source files to exactly match the original version"
- Use "Debug" config
- Use Notepad++ to verify EOL characters

One issue that I thought may have caused this was Intel Parallel Studio Composer XE 2015 for Fortran because it added an inline and optimization option for FPP projects. I have uninstalled and restarted in an attempt to remove any issue from that installation.

Any suggestions will be welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate your frustration. Have you tried relocating the "unbreakable" code into another cpp file to see what happens?

Comment: I moved the code to the top of the function and re-built. I can break the code shown above but now I can't put a breakpoint after line 1079 to the end of the function. However, since the function is written relatively early in the cpp file, I can put a break point in the next function (line 1221) without issue. It's like the end of this one function is permanently corrupt! I do not understand what the problem is.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ He posted the images in order to show the VS 2013 breakpoints. Instead of telling him what not to do (which doesn't help), how would you have posted the information?

Comment: I can repost the code but I wanted to show the breakpoint. It's not really an issue of those lines of code themselves. As stated in the previous comment, I can move and break the code but it still won't let me break or step through the end of this function.

Comment: @MARS One should post code in question as (code formatted) text, that others are able to use it for experimenting with it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That is not what I asked. I know that code should be formatted and posted, but that wasn't the point of his images. Let me ask again: how would you post the information regarding the breakpoints and their specific locations in a method that is easier to understand than images?

Comment: @Johnny I've had strange issues that were sometimes related to complex preprocessor statements. I recommend breaking up the file for now if that helps to mitigate pressing requirements. Also check for unexpected, non-printable characters. You can open the file in something like Scite to view EOL and whitespace characters.

Comment: I appreciate your advice. I used Notepad++ to convert all the files to Unix and back to Windows just to make sure all the EOL characters were in place. Still no luck setting break or stepping through. If you think of anything else, I'd try anything you got.

Comment: If you add /FAs compiler option, check the .asm output for the line before, and line where breakpoint is not working. Also when you are in Visual Studio when you hit line before breakpoint, open the disassembly option, and select it, you can then step through the disassembly live, any findings here let us know. If you could post a code we could reproduce issue that would be great. Also what compiler options used?

Answer (score 0):

I have met this issue before.
try this:

> File->Advanced Save Options->
>   set 'Line endings' to 'Windows (CR LF)'.