# Why would VS2013's debugger place two breakpoints at two different addresses for a single line of code?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

I suspect that we've run into a compiler bug in VS2013. Setting a single breakpoint actually inserts a breakpoint into two different addresses of the code.

I set a breakpoint on line 89 of a source file (`MessageServerManager.cpp`). Here is a snippet of that part of the code (a normal method in a class):

```
87:     void MessageServerManager::setup_dsp_emulation()
88:     {
89:         auto dsp_emulation_setting = util::get_env_var("DSP_EMULATION");
90:         _emulating_dsp = !dsp_emulation_setting.empty();
91: 
92:         if (_emulating_dsp)
```

When  I do this, a single breakpoint appears in VS2013's breakpoint window. However, when the code is built and executed (with optimizations turned off, by the way), the view changes to the following:

[image]

Notice that the two breakpoints are at different addresses. When the first breakpoint is hit, the highlighted line in VS is line 89, but when viewing the disassembly, it's actually in another piece of code (the object's constructor).

Since it's in the objects constructor, it's probably a good idea to share how this object is created. It's a singleton that basically looks like the following:

```
class MessageServerManager : public boost::basic_lockable_adapter < std::recursive_mutex >
{
public:
    inline static MessageServerManager& instance() { static MessageServerManager manager; return manager; }
    void start_dsp_facing_server();
private:
    MessageServerManager();
}
```

And the very first time we're accessing `MessageServerManager`, we're calling `start_dsp_facing_server()` (it's one of the first few lines of `main()`):

```
MessageServerManager::instance().start_dsp_facing_server();
```

The following is the disassembled code of the breakpoint that's in the incorrect location. The C++ code shown is the method the breakpoint should be set on (`start_dsp_facing_server()`), but the disassembled code is obviously different (it's the constructor):

```
    87:     void MessageServerManager::setup_dsp_emulation()
    88:     {
    89:         auto dsp_emulation_setting = util::get_env_var("DSP_EMULATION");
011AAB8F  push        0  
011AAB91  mov         ecx,dword ptr [this]  
011AAB94  add         ecx,8  
011AAB97  call        std::shared_ptr<messaging::IMessageServer>::shared_ptr<messaging::IMessageServer> (010619C9h)  
011AAB9C  mov         byte ptr [ebp-4],1  
    90:         _emulating_dsp = !dsp_emulation_setting.empty();
011AABA0  push        0  
011AABA2  mov         ecx,dword ptr [this]  
011AABA5  add         ecx,10h  
011AABA8  call        std::unique_ptr<radian::SimpleThread,std::default_delete<radian::SimpleThread> >::unique_ptr<radian::SimpleThread,std::default_delete<radian::SimpleThread> > (0106E5CAh)  
011AABAD  mov         byte ptr [ebp-4],2  
    91: 
    92:         if (_emulating_dsp)
    93:         {
```

If I look at the disassembly of the other location of the breakpoint, that part also shows a line 89, but it's the right disassembly.

This is in VS2013 update 4, C++ native application, linked against Boost 1.56.0 and Qt 5.3.1, 32-bit.

Has anyone seen this before, know potential causes, and possible solutions?

I've seen [this question (and the suggestion about line endings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877144/c-vs2013-debugger-breakpoint-not-hit), and I'm aware that optimizations can reorder code and cause odd debugger behavior, but I've batch converted my files to ensure they have proper line endings, and we have optimizations turned off.

I would post a minimal example that shows this behavior, but I'm not able to reproduce this on demand with other code.

Comment: You likely have two different binaries whose PDB contains that line loaded.

Comment: My fellow developer has already checked for that. I've performed a clean on my machine, but it still happens (oh, I should have mentioned this is happening on two different development machines). Tomorrow, I'll blow away everything and pull from source control, and see if that makes a difference. Can't get much cleaner than that.

Comment: I've completely deleted by source/build directories, copied fresh source from version control, and re-built. I experienced the exact same behavior.